# Element occurrences AngularJs Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am quite stuck here, I am fetching a json into a smart table and generating charts from that table, I want to have cross filtering so when a filter is applied the chart updates according to the data visible on the table.

The chart should represents the status of order, The status can be : "Work in progress" "Pending" "Approved" ... I tried to write different functions to count every element occurences but none of them worked:

My code now

```js
$scope.$watch(function() {
      $scope.zdata = $scope.displayed;


      $scope.labels = [];

      $scope.data = [];

      $scope.updatedata = function() {

        //var a = getCount('Approved');
        //$scope.zdata.forEach(function (zdata) {
        $scope.labels.push('Approved', 'Awaiting Verification', 'Work In Progress');
        $scope.data.push('20', '15', '3');
        // $scope.labels.push(zdata.Status);
        // $scope.data.push(zdata.Status.length);



        // }); 
      };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Currently I am showing dummy data just to explain the point.
Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 0):

use instead:

```
$scope.labels = []; // -> $scope.labels.splice(0);
$scope.data = []; // -> $scope.data .splice(0);
//... something else
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried that already I think what I am doing wrong is calculating the occurrences. I tried something more simplistic but that didn't work,
   $scope.zdata.forEach(function (zdata) {
               $scope.labels.push(zdata.Status);
                $scope.data.push(zdata.Status.length  });
Instead of this I guess I should add something else as now it shows very random numbers

Comment: This is what I have now, not sure where I messed it up :

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the easiest possible way using Underscore.js
Thanks for the help